# plot(): text labels at Y axis

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to plot a graph:

```
X-axis: species (setosa,versicolor,virginica)
Y-axis: Sepal.Length
```

on the dataset containing three columns from iris data set: Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Species

I want the Y-axis to be the names of species, but instead it is showing factor values. I tried the command:

```
plot(x = file$Sepal.Length, y = levels(file$Species), col = file$Species)
```

is there any method to view the unique text values as Y-axis using plot() function?

Comment: First you ask for y-axis == Sepal.Length, then you code y=Species??? Might be better to use `boxplot` with `horizontal=TRUE`

Comment: Sorry, I typed wrong while asking the question. the code is right that's how i wanted the axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `yaxt='n'` to the initial `plot()` call to prevent automatic drawing of the y-axis, and then call `axis()` to manually draw your desired y-axis.

```
data(iris);
plot(iris$Sepal.Length,iris$Species,xlab='lol',ylab='lola',col=iris$Species,yaxt='n');
axis(2L,seq_len(nlevels(iris$Species)),levels(iris$Species));
```

[image: plot]

Comment: If this really were the request,( and I suspect not) , then how about using `y=jitter(as.numeric(iris$Species))`?